# Syncing tex source with `savebox`

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

I realize this is quite an edge case, but I am wondering if anyone can help me.

I have source correlation set up in emacs as follows

```lisp
    (setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t
          TeX-source-correlate-mode t
          TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
```

This works great when I am using standard tex commands/environments. However, if I use a `savebox`, the `syncing` is done with the `usebox` command rather than the box's source.

Is there a way to get the syncing with respect to the box's source? Other packages likes `environ` and `mdframed` use this functionality which means their content is never synced.

```latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \newsavebox{\mybox}
    \savebox{\mybox}   % If I comment this line, syncing works
    {
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \lipsum[1]
      \[
        A = B
      \]
      \lipsum[2]
      \[
        C = D
      \]
      \lipsum[3]
      \end{minipage}
    }

    \usebox{\mybox}

    \end{document}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Clicking on a text or equation in the pdf always jumps to the `\usebox{\mybox}`. Can someone shed some light on this? I imagine I would need to save the sync'ing information when saving the box and then "output" them whenever the box is used.